# Why are all my functions being run even though I'm only calling one function in one module?

Tags: f#

I have the following code in a `Test.fs` file:

```
namespace Testing

module test1 =
    let Run =
        printfn "Test1"

module test2 =
    let Run =
        printfn "Test2"
```

In my `Program.fs` I am calling:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    printfn "%A" Testing.test1.Run

    sw.Stop()
    printfn "Problem took %d minutes, %d seconds, and %d milliseconds" sw.Elapsed.Minutes sw.Elapsed.Seconds sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds

    let s = Console.ReadLine()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This outputs

> Test1
>
> Test2

Why is `Test2` being outputting even though I am only calling `Test1.Run` ?

Comment: Same problem.  So confusing.  Who knew?  None of the 10 tutorials I looked at mention this issue.

Comment: same problem here, I thought everything is a function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`test1.Run` is not a function, it is a value.  When you open a module you execute all top-level code in that module.  In this case you are defining `test1.Run` and `test2.Run` which are both bindings rather than functions.

I can't tell from what you posted exactly what is happening, but it's clear that your main function is not getting called, otherwise `printfn "%A" Testing.test1.Run` would print `<null>` and `printfn "Problem took %d minutes, %d seconds, and %d milliseconds" sw.Elapsed.Minutes sw.Elapsed.Seconds sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds` would print something as well.

Comment: It is printing null and the other stuf, I only put the Test1 and Test2 outputs to show what my issue is. And why is `test1.Run` not a function, and how do I make it into a function?

Comment: To tell the compiler that it's a function and not simply a computed value, you need to put `()` after the function name.  In this case, do something like this: `let Run() =
        printfn "Test1"`