# F# function running without being called

Tags: .net, f#

This code

```
open System.Threading

let duration = 1000

module SequentialExample =
    let private someTask item =
        printfn "oh god why"
        Thread.Sleep(duration)
        item + " was computed"

    let private items = [
        "foo"
        "bar"
        "baz"
    ]

    let getComputedItems = 
        printfn "heh"
        [for item in items -> someTask item]
        |> Array.ofList

module ParallelExample =
    let private someTask item =
        printfn "that's ok"
        Thread.Sleep(duration)
        item + " was computed"

    let private items = [
        "foo"
        "bar"
        "baz"
    ]

    let getComputedItems = 
        Async.Parallel [for item in items -> async { return someTask item }]
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    ParallelExample.getComputedItems |> ignore
    0
```

Has the following output:

```
heh
oh god why
oh god why
oh god why
that's ok
that's ok
that's ok
```

If I'm calling `ParallelExample` module, why is F# running the code in `SequentialExample` module?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: essentially, in a module file if at any point the compiler sees something like `let a = ...` it myst calculate the value of `a`

Comment: Do you know why F# compiler works this way?

Comment: well it has to calculate it at some point and the start is the best time.  It is bound to be all defined in the spec somewhere

Comment: This is really weird to me... I thought F# would execute it only when I call the function.

Comment: getcomputeditems isn't a function (which is the whole point)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all my functions being run even though I'm only calling one function in one module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620368/why-are-all-my-functions-being-run-even-though-im-only-calling-one-function-in)

Comment: Hmmm I've made the following changes in the code, now it works as expected ... http://pastebin.com/BHFHtbCH

Comment: Another possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103651/f-how-to-call-let-function-correctly-function-call-in-entrypoint-isnt-wor

Comment: Hmmm now I got it! It's a function only if it takes an argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As John Palmer said in comments, 
`let getComputedItems = ...` 
is actually a value, not a function, **because a function has to take an argument**.

To make it a function, one have to declare it like
`let getComputedItems () = ...`.

Comment: …or `let getComputedItems = … fun () -> …`